# WCF Cant find server certificate using FindBYSubjectName

Tags: .net, wcf, certificate

I have a certificate installed in my test environment. The subject of this is delimited by commas e.g. S80, My Company Name, Country

The code below worked when the subject name was just S80 but now there are more details in the subject it no longer works.

```
  <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="S80, My Company Name, Country" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                 </serviceCredentials>
```

I get an error

**Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'S80, My Company Name, Country'.**

If I just use S80 as the subject I get an error

**Keyset does not exist**

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the certificate by something else? By thumbprint, for instance? Does that work?

Marc

Comment: I think perhaps it can find the certificate as when I use the short subject I get the keyset error. So this is maybe another problem

Answer (score 0):

The 'Keyset does not exist' indicates that the certificate was found by the name 'S80' but that the process account doesn't have read access to the private key of the certificate or that there is no private key available for the certificate.

Seems like the name parts after the comma is ignored.

/Per

Comment: You can edit the private key read permissions for certificates by using the MMC Certificates snap-in and right-click the certificate, select All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys...